# Find installed documentation

Tags: documentation

Where can I find the installed documentation for a library that I have installed?
For example: in `synaptic package manager`, I have installed `opencv-doc`. Where can I find this documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general each Debian package you install also will contain the resulting file location on your system after installation. Packages can be opened and viewed with the Archive Manager.

Alternatively we may also browse a package content on http://packages.ubuntu.com where all packages in the repositories should be listed. For [opencv-doc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/opencv-doc/filelist) this will reveal the following file list:

```
/usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/CMakeLists.txt
/usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/acircles_pattern.png
/usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/changelog.Debian.gz
[...]
```

This package like many other documentation files will therefore install to `/usr/share/doc/<packagename>`.

Answer (score -1):

In terminal you can type `opencv-doc --help` to get the help. You can also try in the finder located on the top left corner and can search there.

Also In Synaptics Package manager, just review the components under the **Installed** sub-tab. You may find your installed programs there.

*UPDATE*

Adding screenshots for more clear flow of actions.

[image: installation of opencv-doc]

[image: Searching the opencv-doc in Ubuntu Software Center]

Comment: doesn't work
`opencv-doc: command not found`. Description does not provide anything useful. Just a description of `opencv` library itself

Comment: Will you please try to reinstall it by root user ?

Comment: @talktokets: synaptic only allows root to install something.

Comment: @Takkat : Thanks, that I know. But here I have suggested to **search** for the installed package. Here one can Use Dash home or Ubuntu Software Center(where the option "Installed") is available.

Comment: @Takkat : Thanks for suggestions. I have added images for more clarification. <br> **Downvoter** : Please specify the correct reason or answer when you downvote. Thanks.

Comment: I cant speak for the downvoter but it seems to me that your answer tells us opencv-doc is installed indeed but it still does not help to find the installed package/files (see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) for a possible approach to this).